# PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype signature ios

Tags: swift, pdf, pdfkit

I want to use PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype signature in my application. But it is not working as expected. I want to sign using Apple Pencil. But the below code is only making a box of given dimensions & not detecting pencil/hand touch.

Here is my code:

```
func addSignature() {

    let bounds = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50)

    let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget, withProperties: nil)
    annotation.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    annotation.color = UIColor.darkGray
    annotation.fieldName = "signature"
    annotation.widgetFieldType = .signature
    annotation.shouldDisplay = true
    annotation.shouldPrint = true
    annotation.widgetControlType = .unknownControl

    let border = PDFBorder()
    border.lineWidth = 2.0
    annotation.border = border
    print("Appareance Stream \(annotation.hasAppearanceStream)")

    pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the `PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype signature` is appropriate *to sign using Apple Pencil*? In PDFs in general there only are  signature form fields for digital signatures (X509 certificate based)...

Comment: Actually there is no description given in PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype signature on apple developer site. If that is the case, can you help me take signature using Apple Pencil using PDFKit in iOS

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. I stumbled over your question because it is tagged PDF, and I happen to know a bit about PDFs in general. I have no knowledge concerning Apple PDF APIs, though.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. May be some one else can help. I have also posted this question on apple developers forum.

Comment: @MeetaLalwani, I am facing the same issue, have you find any solution on this?

Comment: Do u find any solution ? @MeetaLalwani